# __import__ only imports __init__.py

Tags: python

I am having an issue with the `__import__` method. It seems to only import the base directory of the module, but not the file.

For instance I have:

```
test_suite/assert_array_length.py
```

when I pass this into `__import__`:

```
moduleLocation = "test_suite.assert_array_length"
module = __import__(moduleLocation)
print module
```

I am getting:

```
[sub_directories]/test_suite/__init__.pyc
```

The call sequence is going from `run_tests.py` to `test_runner.py`. `test_runner.py` then imports `assert_array_length.py`. They are laid out like this:

```
run_tests.py
|-----------test_runner.py
|-----------assert_array_length.py
```

because it's importing the `__init__.py`, I can't get what I need from the `assert_array_length.py` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__import__` imports the module you asked for. However, if you checked the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__), you would find the following:

> When the *name* variable is of the form `package.module`, normally, **the top-level package (the name up till the first dot) is returned**, not the module named by name.

You may prefer [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html), which will return `package.module` instead of `package` if you tell it to import `package.module`.